# Bounding nonconvex function using convex functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

I need your expertise in getting an insight on the following problem:

Given a nonconvex function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to (0,\infty)$, Is there a way to produce a series $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ of convex functions $g_{i}$ where $i \in [n]$, such that for some constants $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the following applies:
$$ \alpha_1 \cdot \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n g_i(x) \leq f(x) \leq \alpha_2 \cdot \sum\limits_{i=1} g_i(x)$$

If there is a way, can you refer to the actual paper or book?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take $g_{1} (x) = f(x)$, and $g_i = 0 ~ i=2,3,..$ and $n=\alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} = 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I had corrected the question!